# Induced metrics and local isometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry

Well, I'm a bit confused:
If you have a regular surface M at $\mathbb {R}^3$ you have, of course, the Euclidean metric induced. On the other hand, if you have a local parametrization $ \phi: U \to V $ with U open in the plane and V in M, you can induce a metric in M ​​by the Euclidean metric in $ \mathbb {R}^2$. Namely

$$g_{p}(u, v) = <(d\phi^{-1}_{p}.u, d\phi^{-1}_{p}.v>$$

I think that's right. But in one exercise, the assertion is that: "No open set U $\subset S^{2}$ is isometric to an open set W $\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the Euclidean metric. " I think the equation above defines a local isometry and agrees with the statement because not necessarily $ V $ is open in $ M $. Right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium

Comment: Ok, but my question is why this don't (or do) contradicts my defined metric on M by the euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Comment: oh. yes, you can force an isometry between part of the sphere and part of the plane. In the exercise, the implication is that $U$ inherits the metric of the sphere

Comment: I think the point is that your local metric does not coincide with the metric induced from $\mathbb{R}^3$. The exercise refers to a specific metric on $S^2$

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot!